# Unable to fetch data from T24(TAFJ R18) when working with design studio

Tags: jboss, jbase

I faced the below error when importing t24 applications in design studio. The T24 server (TAFJ R18) which I try to connect to is up (jboss is running), but still I face this issue:

```
Unable to fetch data from T24. Check your connection details and if T24 is up and running.
  Subroutine: 
Return Code: FAILURE
Response size: 1
Response 1 ->Response Code: EB-SECURITY.VIOLATION,Response Type: NON_FATAL_ERROR,Response Text: Please check your Login Credential and/or access rights,Response Info: 98748ebf-f73d-4e86-8506-950b2fd0b5d2,
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Username and Password you have provided in the t24-server/config/server.properties is not correct. Make sure you can login to T24 (Browser or Classic) with the T24 User provided in these settings:

```
#T24 User name used for introspection and deployment (TAFJ)
username=INPUTT
#T24 Encrypted password used for introspection and deployment (TAFJ)
password={encoded}gXhuXZkbBuL09T8WFlRR+w==
```

Other important settings in this file:

```
#T24 host name to connect to (IP address or Domain name)
host=localhost
#T24 Web service (TAFJ) port number to connect
ws.port=8080
#Protocol: ftp, sftp or local (TAFC & TAFJ: used for *.b and *.d file transfer)
protocol=ws
#context for web-service
context=axis2
```

Comment: This is Authorisation problem. Either credentials are wrong or expired or blocked

Answer (score 0):

We can check the connectivity and also if anyone restarting the jboss while importing.

1. We can check the server status is "active" in DS, or we can restart the server connectivity.
2. And make sure if you are using any VPN to connect the Database and still it is active.